# Problem with converting std::string to char*

Tags: c++, string, char

I am trying to use a device connected to serial comms. An API given to open the comm port is like this

```
int OpenComport(char * comport, int baudrate);
```

So initially, I define the comport somewhere in my config file

```
//// my config file
#define COMPORT "/dev/ttyUSB0"

//// inmy settings file 
settings->serveraddr_spad = COMPORT;
```

Thinking that I have set all things correctly, I begin to convert string into const char and then into vector (see below).

```
//// in my usage file
std::vector<char> portchar((settings->serveraddr_spad).c_str(), 
                           (settings->serveraddr_spad).c_str() +
                        (settings->serveraddr_spad).size() + 1);

if(OpenComport(  &portchar[0], settings->serverbaud_spad))
{
   // do my action
}
```

All of this seem to agree with the compiler and it run smoothly. However on execution, I found that the port is not opened.

Instead when I switched to this usage of declaring char array outfront, it works(below)

```
char portchar[13] = "/dev/ttyUSB0";

if(OpenComport( portchar, settings->serverbaud_spad))
{
   // do my action
}
```

My question is how to convert std::string into char* for usage?

Regards

Comment: What about `std::string::c_str()`? Btw. `&portchar[0]` should work for `std::string portchar;` as well. Since C++11, a 0 termination of contents is granted for `std::string`. Hopefully, the `OpenComport()` doesn't change the contents of buffer. Otherwise, the `std::string` should be forced to sufficient size beforehand. (Actually, it's not that different to `std::vector<char>` except that `std::string` provides a bit more convenience like e.g. the auto-zero-termination.)

Comment: `c_str()` doesn't seem good because it returns `const char*` while `char*` is requested in this case. Elements of `std::string` are stored continuously, so `&settings->serveraddr_spad[0]` should work.

Comment: Also in later versions of the C++ standard, `std::string` is guaranteed to be null terminated. I forget exactly which version introduced this guaranteee.

Comment: @MikeCAT Agree. My first impression was that the missing `const` for the `char*` parameter is just a relict of an aged API. Though, a modern compiler might complain without a sufficient const-cast, and it wouldn't for the `&portchar[0]` variant.

Comment: @john According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) since C++11. _a pointer to s[0] can be passed to functions that expect a pointer to the first element of a null-terminated (since C++11)CharT[] array._

Comment: But based on [my experiment](https://wandbox.org/permlink/E3cppqQtvqNNZUog), I think that the `vector` version also should work. There may be some other bugs. Did you verify the contents of `settings` and the vector `portchar`?

Answer (score 0):

You should almost never need `vector<char>`, instead just use:

```
if(OpenComport( (char*) settings->serveraddr_spad.c_str(), settings->serverbaud_spad))
```

Comment: This code will lead into compilation error like `error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*'`

Comment: @MikeCAT added cast, so it will compile just fine

Comment: @lenik you should be using `const_cast` instead of a C-style cast: `OpenComport( const_cast<char*>(settings->serveraddr_spad.c_str()), ...)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`std::string::data()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data). In contrast to `c_str()` it returns a `char *` for non-const strings. Since C++11 it's garantued, that the returned array will be null-terminated.

```
if(OpenComport(settings->serveraddr_spad.data(), settings->serverbaud_spad))
{
   // do my action
}
```